# React Native - hiding the navigation bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to hide the navigation at specific routes. How can I do it with `Navigator`? Is it something that can be done with `NavigatorExperimental`?

Answer (score 1):

Note routing using the official RN API is still clumsy.  Highly suggest using this library for routing:

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Check out the gif on the detailed example for the use cases:

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/DETAILED_EXAMPLE.md

Comment: I know that `react-native-router-flux` but it was giving me a lot of trouble in my application, felt more comfortable working with the Navigator but I guess I will give it another try. Thank you :)